# Checkbox retorna sempre false quando faço .is(":checked");

Tags: javascript

Código é este:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("funfo");
    $("#segunda").click(function () {
        var check = $("#segunda").is(":checked");
        if (check == "true") {
            alert("true");
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
        alert(check);
    });
});
</script>
```

Problema é, o cara seleciona a checkbox, retorna `false`, ele desmarca, retorna `false`.. sendo que `true` retorna quando a caixa é selecionada, e `false` quando é desselecionada..

Eu usei um `alert(check);` e ele retorna `true`, e `false`, para marcado e não marcado, exatamente como era para fazer, mas na verificação do `IF` ele sempre retorna uma opção, que no caso é `false`..

Comment: voce esta checando se a var check eh igual a "true"(string) inves de testar se ela eh `true` (note sem as aspas)

Comment: Verdade.. eu pensei que, uma variavel recebendo um valor, o valor virava string, mas como não há declaração de tipo de variavel, acho que é por isso que ela acaba se "adequando" ao que foi sugerido ela receber.. 
obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("funfo");
    $("#segunda").click(function () {
        var check = this.checked;
        if (check) alert("true");
        else alert("false");
        alert('O valor do check é: ' + check);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="segunda" />
```

Quando você usa `.is(":checked")` isso vai retornar um Booleano. Ou seja `true` ou `false`. Na sua comparação está a comparar com `"true"`. Quando usa aspas está a usar o tipo String e não Booleano. Assim a comparação deve ser `if (check == true){`. Na verdade essa comparação é desnecessária, basta fazer `if (check){`.

Um outro aspeto que pode mudar (e mudei no código do exemplo da resposta) é que não precisa de `$("#segunda").is(":checked")`, pode usar JavaScript puro, sem jQuery, (this.checked) uma vez que está à procura do `checked` do elemento que foi clicado. (Quanto menos jQuery melhor...).